# 3 inputs for a oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have below query:

```
where POSTDATE between to_date('&START_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('&END_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') 
and username='&username'
```

But my requirements are:

1. I need all usernames between Start date & End date(3rd Input is
   blank) AND / OR
2. specified usernames(in 3rd Input) between provided
   start date and End date in query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! So, what have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: what do you mean AND/OR?  Please edit the question and show sample data and expected output.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want the date range check anyway, then you either want all users or a specified user; so you can check if you were given a username:

```
where POSTDATE between to_date('&START_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('&END_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') 
and ('&&username' is null or username='&&username')
```

If no user name is given then the second line evaluates to:

```
and ('' is null or username='')
```

In Oracle `''` is equivalent to null (though they have always warned that could change one day...) so the first clause is true.

You haven't said if you're explicitly prompting for the inputs (with `accept`); if you are then you could use single & or double &&, but if not [using double && will prevent you being asked twice](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-DAEF8542-1042-4F98-9C68-CED90AC42A79).

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bit, actually my actual qury is in Joins as Below